# Solving $u_t-u_{xx}=u(1-u)$ with initial/boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

How would one go about solving, or describing the solutions to this non-linear PDE, the heat equation with an extra non-linear term.

$$u_t-u_{xx}=u(1-u)$$
Suppose,

$$u=u(x,t),\quad x\in[0,L],\quad u(L,t)=0=u(0,t), \quad u(x,0)=f(x)$$

However i'm not too worried about specific initial/boundary conditions, just looking for a nice way to attack this.

For instance perhaps:

$$f(x)= \delta_{x,L/2} $$

Comment: Fourier method.

Comment: So separation of variables then Fourier series solution, or Fourier transform?

Comment: I like the look of this, would you be able to elaborate on your expression for $w$, can't entirely see how you arrived to that?

Comment: Yes. (I delete my previous comment, because that way was for $u_t-u_{xx}=u(1-u)+ g(x,t)$)

Comment: So here, just try to find your solution with Fourier method ($u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$). If you have some problem, tell me,  I will try to solve then equation.

Comment: @Cortizol: I see, ok many thanks

Comment: Are you looking for periodic solutions? since equations like this may have a solution in terms of travelling wave solutions? i.e. $z=x-ct$. 

The resultant stationary equation would be
$$
u^{''}+cu^{'} + u(1-u) = 0.
$$
Which you could try and solve.

Comment: I don't see where @Cortizol is going with the separation of variables in a nonlinear PDE. The suggestion by Chinny84 is sound, but even that ODE can be tricky to solve explicitly. In general, to find an explicit solution of a nonlinear PDE takes a miracle; there is no method that produces such solutions (no "nice ways to attack"). Numerical methods are there; and theory helps with qualitative properties of solutions, such as growth/decay, maximum principle, etc. Explicitly... I think the equilibrium state, with $u_t=0$, is about as much as you'll get.

Comment: @PostNoBills I totally agree separation of variables is only for linear equations or I have heard of weakly nonlinear but even in that scenario you assume quasi linearity and remove nonlinear terms. The ODE I gave should have solutions as it looks like the fisher equation which has solutions for specific "c" values..you could also look at the tanh-coth expansions as a kink solution should be present..hence my question in the comment, does the solutions have to be periodic?

Comment: That equation is called the Fisher equation and you can look at Polyanin & Zaitsev's Handbook of Nonlinear PDEs book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just looking for a nice way to attack this.

Would you like a pony with that? It's a nonlinear PDE.

> How would one go about solving, or describing the solutions

By reading the existing literature on [Fisher's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_equation) (which is what it is, as pointed out in comments). It is known to have traveling wave solutions for various speeds, and — miraculously — solutions with speed $5/\sqrt{6}$ have an explicit form such as 
$$u(x,t) = \left\{1+\exp\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}} -\frac{5t}{6}\right) \right\}^{-2} $$ This solution is pictured below (times $t=-5,-4,\dots,4,5$ are represented by colors changing  from magenta to cyan):

[image]

Looks like a tide that never goes back down.

For more, see [EqWorld entry](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/npde/npde1101.pdf) and the references cited there, in particular

- Danilov, V. G., Maslov V. P., and Volosov, K. A., *Mathematical Modelling of Heat and Mass Transfer Processes*, Kluwer, Dordrecht, 1995.
- Polyanin, A. D. and Zaitsev, V. F., *Handbook of Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations*, Chapman & Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, 2004.